# Mininet Switch Port Mirroring Configuration

Tags: python, linux, mininet

I am new in using Mininet and wondering how to configure Switch (preferably in python using native Switch class)in order to duplicate all the traffic on the certain port connected to host with Wireshark launched to be ablee see all the traffic. Any suggestions?

There is my configuration script:

```
class MyTopo( Topo ):
"Simple topology example."

def __init__( self ):
    "Create custom topo."

# Initialize topology
Topo.__init__( self )

    # Add hosts and switches
leftHost = self.addHost( 'h1' )
rightHost = self.addHost( 'h2' )
idsHost = self.addHost( 'h3' )
    Switch = self.addSwitch( 's1' )


    # Add links
    self.addLink( leftHost,Switch )
    self.addLink( rightHost, Switch )
    self.addLink( Switch, idsHost )


topos = { 'mytopo': ( lambda: MyTopo() ) }
```

Answer (score 0):

To see the switch's traffic on the host (say h1) having Wireshark. The host needs to get each packet incoming in that switch. You can write a RYU controller for that switch which along with passing the packet to appropriate host (say h2) also passes the packet to h1. You can have a look at https://osrg.github.io/ryu-book/en/html/switching_hub.html
This is switching hub, that is packet incoming to the switch will be forwarded to all interfaces other than the incoming interface. You need to change it such that switch forwards to h1's interface irrespective of intended host.